# how can I load data from cassandra into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, elasticsearch-plugin

I am new to elasticsearch, and my application requires to load data from Cassandra to elasticsearch.After searching alot, I found this blog on elasticsearch documentation.

`https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers`

But River plugin is depricated now. So,what are the other ways to do this?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/load-cassandra-data-into-elasticsearch/38590/2

Comment: You can try https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc with http://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Could you please provide more information? As I have already gone through these links.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

[Elassandra](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra)

Elassandra is a fork of Elasticsearch modified to run as a plugin for Apache Cassandra